# kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell with enable Kerberos Security on Kafka 1.0

Tags: apache-kafka

I enabled the Kerberos Authentication on Kafka 1.0. When I try to kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list :9092 --topic  --time -1, It hits error. Here are the Error,

> [kafka@KLBIRKFKI1 kafka_2.11-1.0.1]$ bin/kafka-run-class.sh
>   kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list klbirkfki1:9092 --topic
>   abdullah --time -1
>
> [2018-06-26 12:59:00,058] WARN Fetching topic metadata with
>   correlation id 0 for topics [Set(abdullah)] from broker
>   [BrokerEndPoint(0,klbirkfki1,9092)] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)

java.io.EOFException

```
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:124)

    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.readCompletely(BlockingChannel.scala:131)

    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.receive(BlockingChannel.scala:122)

    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:82)

    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:79)

    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:124)

    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:63)

    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:98)

    at kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell$.main(GetOffsetShell.scala:79)

    at kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell.main(GetOffsetShell.scala)
```

Exception in thread "main" kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(abdullah)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(BrokerEndPoint(0,klbirkfki1,9092))] failed

```
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:77)

    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:98)

    at kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell$.main(GetOffsetShell.scala:79)

    at kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell.main(GetOffsetShell.scala)
```

Caused by: java.io.EOFException

```
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:124)

    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.readCompletely(BlockingChannel.scala:131)

    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.receive(BlockingChannel.scala:122)

    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:82)

    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:79)

    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:124)

    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:63)

    ... 3 more
```

[kafka@KLBIRKFKI1 kafka_2.11-1.0.1]$ bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list klbirkfki1:9092 --topic abdullah --time -1

[2018-06-26 12:59:00,058] WARN Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 0 for topics [Set(abdullah)] from broker [BrokerEndPoint(0,klbirkfki1,9092)] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)

java.io.EOFException

```
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:124)

    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.readCompletely(BlockingChannel.scala:131)

    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.receive(BlockingChannel.scala:122)

    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:82)

    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:79)

    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:124)

    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:63)

    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:98)

    at kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell$.main(GetOffsetShell.scala:79)

    at kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell.main(GetOffsetShell.scala)
```

Exception in thread "main" kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(abdullah)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(BrokerEndPoint(0,klbirkfki1,9092))] failed

```
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:77)

    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:98)

    at kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell$.main(GetOffsetShell.scala:79)

    at kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell.main(GetOffsetShell.scala)
```

Caused by: java.io.EOFException

```
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:124)

    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.readCompletely(BlockingChannel.scala:131)

    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.receive(BlockingChannel.scala:122)

    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:82)

    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:79)

    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:124)

    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:63)

    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Is this a programming question or a question about using software?

Comment: Did you try KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS? 
`export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/devel/TEST_COMMAND_LINE_CONNECTIONS/jaas.conf -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf"`